# javascript var a1 and call with alert(a+1) string and number

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, numbers

i am newbie here.. this my first post.. please help me how to call example:-

```
var a1 = "car";
var n = 1;
alert(a+n); // not working
alert((a+1)); // not working
alert([a+n]); // not working
alert(a+[n]); // not working
```

i want combine string and number to return alert.. i mean not return with alert(a1) ..

```
same with id :-
var a1 = document.getElementById("myid");
a1.value = "car";
alert(a+n.value); // not working
alert((a+1).value); // not working
alert([a+n].value); // not working
alert(a+[n].value); // not working
```

in php :

$n = 1;
echo "

var a".$n." = 'car';
alert(a".$n."); // i want similar like this

";

how about javascript??..

```
thanks 1000x....
```

Comment: you never declare `a`.

Comment: If you want to declare dinamic name of var you can use eval(a+n) or window[a+n]

Comment: sorry.. please give me example how to solve this and how to call alert(a1) as alert("a"+1) or etc...

Comment: @stefino76... var a1= "car"; aa = window[a+1]; alert(aa); //but still nor working..

Comment: var a1= "car";
n = 1;
aa = eval(a+n);
alert(aa); //same not working

Comment: Try window['a'+'1']

Comment: @stefino76.. thanks.. aa = window["a"+"1"]; is working now.. i more question.. how about id attribute.. ?

Comment: all is solve... id and variables together works... thanks to all again..